# nm-applet alternative ? wifi eth conflict ? network inspection tools?

Tags: networking, networkmanager

I'm on a Debian box :

```
$ cat /etc/debian_version 
11.2
$ uname -r 
4.19.0-17-amd64
```

I have a strange network problem (slowdown or no connection at all) that disappears when I reboot.

It seems to frequently appear after connecting with ethernet and then going back to wifi on another location. How can this happen?? Also, it seems to depend on the application??

Thx for any background understanding, hints or suggestion of network tools etc.

Comment: Have you looked at `sar` output to see if it happens at certain times?

Comment: @MarkStewart sorry what's `sar` ? Nothing clear came along when I did some

`$ apt search sar`

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  See https://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/sar/  -- SAR is a daemon that runs every so often to capture all sorts of statistics on disk, network, CPU, etc.

Comment: Ok so I should have tried `man sar`... So the usage for example would be

`sar -n DEV  -m ALL 1 1` : this would print network device activity and all power management statistics 1 time after 1 sec. (My installation does not have the `-a` options like in above link).

Or look into the log files at `/var/log/...`. I'm not sure if it will suffice though, but thx anyway...